# Regular expression not matching end of string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse the following strings, and anything in `{}` needs to stay in one chunk. The rest of the symbols need to stay, but be in their own array key.

```
$string_1 = ({Product.Depth+1.25=2.5&2.0+2.0=4}+{1.0+2.5=3.0&2.0+3.0=5.0})-(16.75+10.9375)
$string_2 = Product.Width+[{1.0+1.0=2.0|2.0+3.0=4}?100.00:0.00]
$string_3 = [1+1=2?10.00:Product.Depth]
```

Here's what I've got so far which works for the top two, but not the third string.

```
preg_match_all("/[()=]|\\{[^\}]+\\}|[+-]|[^=]+$/", $string_to_parse, $matches);
```

Right now it returns something like this...You can see it's missing a few numbers between keys 7,8,9.  And key 14 dropped some numbers also.

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(15) {
[0]=>
string(1) "="
[1]=>
string(1) "("
[2]=>
string(13) "{1+1=2&2+2=4}"
[3]=>
string(1) "+"
[4]=>
string(13) "{1+2=3&2+3=5}"
[5]=>
string(1) ")"
[6]=>
string(1) "="
[7]=>
string(1) "+"
[8]=>
string(1) "+"
[9]=>
string(1) "+"
[10]=>
string(13) "{1+1=2|2+3=4}"
[11]=>
string(1) "-"
[12]=>
string(1) "+"
[13]=>
string(1) "="
[14]=>
string(7) "2?10:0]"
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand exactly what you're attempting here. Are you trying to match symbols / operators / groups, and not individual digits? Perhaps a little more clarification, as well as actual code being tested (such as showing us `$string_to_parse` rather than test strings - _actual_ code).

Comment: Can you provide us the expected output for all the 3 strings mentioned by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern: `~\{[^}]*\}|\d+|.~` [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxWUKw/1)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gXX2L))

```
$strings = [
    '({1+1=2&2+2=4}+{1+2=3&2+3=5})-(16+10)',
    '10+[{1+1=2|2+3=4}?100:0]',
    '[1+1=2?10:0]'
];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_export(preg_match_all('~\{[^}]*\}|\d+|.~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '(',
  1 => '{1+1=2&2+2=4}',
  2 => '+',
  3 => '{1+2=3&2+3=5}',
  4 => ')',
  5 => '-',
  6 => '(',
  7 => '16',
  8 => '+',
  9 => '10',
  10 => ')',
)
array (
  0 => '10',
  1 => '+',
  2 => '[',
  3 => '{1+1=2|2+3=4}',
  4 => '?',
  5 => '100',
  6 => ':',
  7 => '0',
  8 => ']',
)
array (
  0 => '[',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '+',
  3 => '1',
  4 => '=',
  5 => '2',
  6 => '?',
  7 => '10',
  8 => ':',
  9 => '0',
  10 => ']',
)
```

---

As for your question extension criteria, the pattern just needs to be adjusted for `letter`-`dot`-`letter` sequences as well as float values.

`preg_match_all()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FhsiW)):

```
preg_match_all('~\{[^}]*\}|\d*\.?\d+|[a-z]+\.[a-z]+|.~i', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : []
```

or if you'd like to see `preg_split()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jkTQ3)):

```
preg_split('~(\{[^}]*\}|[^\w.])~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

*Note, if you want/need to identify signed numbers (positive/negative) by binding the leading sign with the number (but not match `+` and `-` operators), then additional adjustment is required.  I'll not go down this rabbit hole, unless you explicitly state that this is a requirement for your actual project.

As for explaining these patterns, the formal explanation is automatically delivered whenever you write your input string and pattern into regex101.com (or the like).

Beyond that, I can offer some casual explanations:

```
~               #Pattern delimiter (There are many valid delimiters, this is a wise choice because the tilde is not used inside the actual pattern.  This avoids having to perform any unnecessary escaping.)
\{[^}]*\}       #Match (as much as possible) { followed by zero or more characters that are not } then match }
|               #Or
\d*\.?\d+       #Match (as much as possible) zero or more digits, followed by an optional dot, followed by one or more digits. (This allows "0.999" and ".1" but not "99." )
|               #Or
[a-z]+\.[a-z]+  #Match (as much as possible) one or more letters, followed by a dot, followed by one or more letters.
|               #Or
.               #Match any single non-newline character (this is intended to pick up all of the symbols/left-overs).
~               #Pattern Delimiter
i               #Case-insensitive pattern modifier: this makes the regex engine treat every [a-z] like [a-zA-Z]
```

...another deep breath...

`preg_split()` is a versatile version of `explode()`.  The pattern tells it every instance where an explosion should occur.

```
~          #Pattern delimiter
(          #Start capture group
\{[^}]*\}  #Match (as much as possible) { followed by zero or more characters that are not } then match }
|          #Or
[^\w.]     #Match any single character that is not a letter, number, underscore, or dot (same effect as: "[a-zA-Z0-9_.]").  This is intended to "catch" all of the symbols that are meant to be singled-out.
)          #End capture group
~          #Pattern delimiter
```

In other words, this *explodes* on every curly bracketed expression or symbol.  This alone doesn't work as required -- flags must be declared on this function call.

Parameter 3 is `0` this tells the `preg_split()` to match an unlimited number of times.  This is the default behavior of the function, but for parameter 4 to work we need to use this placeholder.

Parameter 4 has two parts.  Declaring more than one flag requires the use of a pipe `|` to separate them.

- `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` : This tells the function to retain the substrings that are used as "points of explosion".  With out this flag, the output array would not contain any of the curly bracketed expressions or symbols.  If we weren't going to use this flag, then the capture group brackets would be needless in the pattern.
- `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` : When two "points of explosion" are side-by-side, the result is an empty array element.  In many cases (and this case specifically), these empty elements are not desirable; this flag eliminates the need to call `array_filter()` to mop-up the mess.

Comment: Thats perfect!  Thank you very much. I'd love to understand how it works, because reading documentation doesn't teach a learning disabled person like myself

Comment: I'd love to be able to do a chat with you if you're open to that.  I believe if i had someone to answer questions about regex i could finally understand it better.

Comment: There's one thing I neglected to add to this, if you wouldn't mind helping one last time.  I need the ability to capture a variable such as `Product.Width`.  I have updated the string in the OP.  The variables should be kept together similar to the `{}` statements

Comment: Did i do this correctly for my previous question. `\{[^}]*\}|\d+|\w+\.\w+|.`

Comment: My pattern was assuming that all numbers in your string would be whole numbers (no decimals). If this is true then your new pattern will work fine.  I don't know if I have time for chat today (certainly not from my phone - typing is too slow / uncomfortable).  I'll update my answer with explanation when I get to my computer.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it.  Yes it does need to work with decimals.  I shouldn't have been testing with whole numbers.  Let me update the OP

Comment: thanks for the help.  I can understand that when you lay it out.  I appreciate you taking the time.  Sadly, I'll have to post another question this morning on regex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164497/discussion-between-joeb-and-mickmackusa).